# Как подключить youtube-dl скрипт в ios-приложение?

Tags: python, objective-c, ios, youtube-api

Как подключить [youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/index.html) скрипт в своем ios-приложении?
Скрипт этот может быть в двух видах:

1. Несколько *.py файлов (питон скрипты)
2. Один исполнимый файл командной строки "youtube-dl" (можно спокойно запускать в терминале как отдельную команду)

В проекте имеется встроенная Python-библиотека (фреймворк):

```
#include <Python/Python.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

Зачем вам этот скрипт, если есть куча альтернатив? Навскидку, [youtube helper](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper) - официально от [гугла](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper), [YoutubePlayer](https://github.com/JV17/YoutubePlayer), [XCDYouTubeKit](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit) (тут можно заполучить прямые ссылки на скачивание)

Comment: Спасибо за ссылки на библиотеки, но дело не в самом youtube, а в списке множества других сайтов, с которых youtube-dl также парсит видео-ссылки. Т.е. нам нужен такой парсер видео-ссылок с множества сайтов, в особенности стала сейчас задача найти такой парсер с флеш сайтов, для извлечения url на flv-видео.

Comment: Ну тогда либо найти подходящие библиотеки, либо перевести код с питона на objective-c/swift, либо реализовать самим. Код обычно очень простой, я сам делал выдёргивание с ютуба, всё делается довольно тривиально. Интерпретатор питона в айфон-приложении внедрять просто бессмысленно имхо.

Comment: Свои наработки уже имеются на javascript. Сейчас стоит задача парсить видео ссылки с флеш плееров. Нашел либу на Си  libquvi, думаю как подключить к XCode в IOS проект.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30613212/how-can-i-build-libquvi-for-ios